# How to save WordPress cookie so that user becomes loggedin using javascript and AJAX only, without any plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to login into WordPress using ajax only.
Here is my code

```
var username = data.username;
var password = data.password;
var wp_login_url = "http://local_Ip/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=" +username + "&password=" + password + "&insecure=cool";

$.ajax({
        url: wp_login_url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data, status) {
          // if status = "okey"
         console.log("Success!!");
         console.log(data);
         console.log(status);
         // write code here to store the cookie
         // do other task once used is logged in.
        }
      });
```

It is working fine and I am getting response too.
This is the data I am receiving.

{

```
  "status": "ok",
  "cookie": "some_name|1489727386|JpJ5CP4tafjsvcmwKIgSwF3n0YcceHHp951RQ5pL66h|72f3c19d3012f907a2d9ca65c09d068f7f135bc9dd58910521f274e6156613eb",
  "cookie_name": "wordpress_logged_in_ea481ff90802a841ac44175284812226",
  "user": {
    "id": 60,
    "username": "some_name",
    "nicename": "some_name",
    "email": "9**********@something.org",
    "url": "",
    "registered": "2017-03-02 11:28:34",
    "displayname": "some_name",
    "firstname": "",
    "lastname": "",
    "nickname": "",
    "description": "",
    "capabilities": "",
    "avatar": null
  }
}
```

I want to store the cookie in browser using javascript (no php) so that user is becomes logged in to WordPress and then complete some other javascript task.
I am new in this. I don't understand this very well.

Comment: I would use php, if u use JavaScript to process login sessions you will need a fallback to some kind of server side code anyway is user disables js

Comment: I don't know know php and don't have time to learn php.
I am getting the cookie. All I need is to store the cookie. Thats my understand of how login works.

Mark me if I am incorrect.

Comment: Like I said it can be done but is not a good method, if the user disables js in there browser how will the login work. Php or some other server side language will be required

Comment: you are right, Disabling javascript in browser will be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format to set a cookie is

```
    document.cookie="cookie_name=cookie_value; expires=proper date format(UTC); path=/";
```

So to set cookie you need to define a function

```
   function setCookie(cookie_name,cookie_value,expiry_date){
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + (expiry_date*24*60*60*1000));
       var expires = "expires="+ date.toUTCString();
       document.cookie = cookie_name+ "=" + cookie_value+ ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }
```

This sets your cookie.
Now to get the cookie you need to define another function

```
    function getCookie(cookie_name) {
      var name = cookie_name+ "=";
      var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
      var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
      for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
         while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
             c = c.substring(1);
         }
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
             return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
         }
    }
    return "";
  }
```

Now you can use the set function in your ajax success function.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: wp_login_url,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data, status) {
      // if status = "okey"
     console.log("Success!!");
     console.log(data);
     console.log(status);
     // write code here to store the cookie
     this.setCookie(data.cookie_name,data.cookie,expiryDate);//expiryDate is any date you want to get the cookie expired on.
     // do other task once used is logged in.
    }
  });
```

To delete a cookie give the expiry date as a past date. The browser sees the cookie is expired and deletes it.
Hope that helps. :)

Comment: That helped.
Thanks